# Conditional formatting on a table

Tags: jquery, html, css, formatting

I'm trying to add conditional formatting to the following;

```
<tr>
    <td><h3>Company</h3></td>
    <td><h3>Price</h3></td>
    <td><h3>Change</h3></td>
</tr>     

<tr>
    <td>Example</td>
    <td>123.4</td>
    <td>-1</td>
</tr>
```

Where if column "change" is 0 or below the font is red, and green if else.

I found this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ty497/, which I can adapt, but I can't get it to only work on the third column.

Answer (score 5):

Simply change the jQuery selector to `$('tbody tr td:nth-child(3)')` so that it only applies to the third cell of each row.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through the provided link.

The solution for your problem is to change the code in two places:

1. Change the condition in the function for poor is `1` and very poor to `0`.
2. Change the color for poor in the css part.